# How to call javascript interop method in different components in Blazor server side

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Might be a silly question. But is there a way to re-use methods that call Javascript functions in runtime?

So let's say I have `EditBox.razor` component that has this function

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
...
Some HTML code
...

@code{
...
    private async Task RenderSyntax()
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("Prism.highlightAll");
    }
...
```

Now I want to call this method in some other component `Foo.razor`. Without having reference, so statically.

Do I create a static class model for generic `Javascript.razor` components where I define all my javascript interops that are called by different components and make all other components inherit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a helper class for e.g. JSInteropHelper. This will have your reusable methods that you want to use in multiple pages.

```
// Have kept the method as static so I don't need to create a instance of it.
internal static ValueTask<object> HighlightText(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
{
    return jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("Prism.highlightAll");
}
```

In your razor component you can just pass the `JSRuntime` as parameter.

```
@code{

    private async Task RenderSyntax()
    {
        await JSInteropHelper.HighlightText(JSRuntime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That is literally what I did yesterday, I just forgot to update this question. Thank you for the answer again.

Answer (score 0):

this is the idea of Dependency Injection (DI)
a static class is a kind of DI singleton object.
So dont do it an take the way Microsoft decided.
You can encapsulate this logic into a wrapper class (mylib)  and attach it to the di list in startup.cs like AddSingleton
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

As HannesPreishuber mentioned, you can create a class and add all your methods in it and use that class everywhere via [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Here is an example code:

```
public class JsMethods : IJsMethods
{
    private readonly IJSRuntime _jSRuntime;

    public JsMethods(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
    {
        _jSRuntime = jSRuntime;
    }

    public async Task RenderSyntax(string identifier)
    {
        //.. some other code

        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync(identifier);

        //.. some other code
    }
}
```